# system(): pass argument with qoutes

Tags: c, system

I try to call the shell command `xvkbd` with `system()` from my C programm and controll Kicad/Pcbnew with that.

```
system("xvkbd -text 'n' -window Pcbnew*");
```

Works fine

But when I try to add the control key it fails

```
system("xvkbd -text '\Cn' -window Pcbnew*");
```

When I execute `xvkbd -text '\Cn' -window Pcbnew*` direct on the shell it works.

Have anyone a idea how to pass the qoutes correctly?
I tryed several ways like `\` before the qoutes.

Comment: Try `\\\` instead...

Comment: You need `"...\\..."` to produce a string that contains a backslash.

Comment: In a C string the \ is an "escape" character which expects another character to follow. If you really do want a \ character you must have it twice. This is a similar situation with `printf` format specifiers, where in addition you must escape the `%` character with `%%` if you really want a `%` in the output - not used as a format specifier.